# Jquery show only part of image on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want only part of the image to be visible when scrolling. I have an image with text on top and I want to see only text when scrolling. I can't just write that text, it must be image.

How can I show a specific part of the page? I can change image on scroll, maybe I need to just cut off the necessary part? Here is my code. Just for example I need to see top 10% of the image

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() == 0) {
    $('.test').attr('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/80/140-P1020281_-_Flickr_-_Laurie_Nature_Bee.jpg');
  } else {
    $('.test').attr('src', 'https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-01/1547365376_1.jpg');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="test" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/80/140-P1020281_-_Flickr_-_Laurie_Nature_Bee.jpg">
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. When the user scrolls down you somehow want to stop the image being displayed except its text...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, text is a part of image. So i want to see only part of image.

Comment: There is no text in the image in your example? Why make the image bigger than the text so that scrolling is an issue in the first place? If the user scrolls, what are you expecting to show instead of the bottom of the image?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i dint find  similar image I just want to see a specific part of the image, it's like cropping image.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it inside a parent div and manipulate it's height.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <img class="test" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/80/140-P1020281_-_Flickr_-_Laurie_Nature_Bee.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  height:100v;
}

.parent.partial {
  height: 10vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.test {
  width: 100vh;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.test').attr('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/80/140-P1020281_-_Flickr_-_Laurie_Nature_Bee.jpg');
  
  if ($(document).scrollTop() == 0) {
    $('.parent').removeClass('partial');
  } else {
    $('.parent').addClass('partial');
  }
});
```